How to plot the Information Architecture for a label which is not a page?
I am using Visual vocabulary quick reference by Jesse James Garrett (http://www.jjg.net/ia/visvocab/)
I am not clear about what item to use (from above linked vocabulary) to show a label which is not a page. For eg. I have a drop down named 'Pets' and there are two children pages called 'Cats' & 'Dogs' but there is no page for 'Pets'; it is just a drop down.
How can I plot this in an IA diagram?

You will need one of the conditional elements: http://www.jjg.net/ia/visvocab/#conconcept

I am not very familiar with Jesse James Garret's work on IT, but as pointed out from the link in the question:

When describing information architecture, the diagram should emphasize
conceptual structure and organization of content. Note that conceptual
structure is not the same as navigational structure. The objective of
the information architecture diagram is not to provide a full-blown
navigational specification; this level of detail is best kept in other
documents, where it is less likely to confuse and distract.

So it suggests that this is used to organize the conceptual structure of content, and not how things would be implemented in the website navigation.
If you want a real example of how this looks in real life, in Google Sites there is a distinction between pages, menu items and menu sections. A menu section is a menu item that provides links to pages but is not a page itself. A menu item is something that appears on the navigation that can be a page or a menu section. A page is a container for content that can be a menu item.
